# Filtering based on a value inside array of object using DataWeave 2.0

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

Below is my input JSON

```
{
"context": "context",
"meetings": [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "subject": "subject 123",
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user1",
                    "address": "user1@gmail.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "!user2",
                    "address": "user2@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 456,
        "subject": "subject 456",
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user3",
                    "address": "user3@gmail.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user4",
                    "address": "user4@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

From the above JSON, First, I want to filter out the objects where name of the user starts with `!` and in each resultant object, I want to add a new attribute `email` where `email` is the email of the attendee whose name starts with `!`. Below is my expected output:

```
[
{
"id": 123,
"subject": "subject 123",
"attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user1",
                    "address": "user1@gmail.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "!user2",
                    "address": "user2@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ],
"email" : "user2@gmail.com"
}
]
```

I am completely new to DataWeave. can someone please help me in getting the expected output.

I tried with the below code

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
payload.meetings filter ((item, index) -> item.attendees.emailAddress.name startsWith  "!") map (
{
  "id" : $.id,
  "subject" : $.subject,
  "attendees" : $.attendees,
  "email" : ($.attendees filter $.emailAddress.name startsWith  "!")[0].emailAddress.address
})
```

But it turned out to be below **error** :

```
You called the function 'startsWith' with these arguments: 
  1: Array (["user1", "user2"])
  2: String ("!")

But it expects arguments of these types:
  1: String
  2: String

4| payload.meetings filter ((item, index) -> item.attendees.emailAddress.name startsWith  "!") map (
```

Comment: Please use code blocks for input , dataweave code and output for readability. What is the expected output if there are more than one user with name that startsWith "!" ?

Comment: Hi @StackOverflowed, in our case, there cannot be more than one user whose name starts with "!".. Apologies for the bad readable code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this script would help you.

**Input**

```
{
"context": "context",
"meetings": [
    {
        "id": 123,
        "subject": "subject 123",
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user1",
                    "address": "user1@gmail.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "!user2",
                    "address": "user2@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 456,
        "subject": "subject 456",
        "attendees": [
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user3",
                    "address": "user3@gmail.com"
                }
            },
            {
                "type": "required",
                "emailAddress": {
                    "name": "user4",
                    "address": "user4@gmail.com"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

**Code**

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::util::Values
import * from dw::core::Arrays
var filteredInput = (payload.meetings update "attendees" 
                        with (if ($.emailAddress.name some ($ startsWith  "!")) $ 
                              else null )) filter $.attendees != null
output application/json 
---
filteredInput map {
  Id: $.id,
  subject: $.subject,
  attendees: $.attendees map {
    "type": $."type",
    emailAddress: $.emailAddress
  },
  email: do{
      var email =  ($.attendees.emailAddress filter ($.name startsWith  "!")).address
      ---
      if(sizeOf(email) == 1) email[0] else email
  }
}
```

**Output**

```
[
  {
    "Id": 123,
    "subject": "subject 123",
    "attendees": [
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "user1",
          "address": "user1@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "!user2",
          "address": "user2@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "email": "user2@gmail.com"
  }
]
```

In case only one name has the "!" character, the email will be a string, if there is more than one match, it will be an array.

Comment: Thanks for your input @LeanCabeza. My requirement is that the output should contain the entire object which has atleast one attendees.emailAddress.Name starts with "!". If the name starts with "!", the resultant object should contain the entire attendees rather than just the one starts with "!". In my case, it should return the entire object with id : 123 as it has atleast one attendee whose name starts with "!".

Comment: Also, in our case, there wont be more than one attendees whose name starts with "!". so, email attribute should be "string"

Comment: @user3286888 I already updated the code, please try it again! :D

Comment: Thanks a lot @LeanCabeza!!! Your code worked like charm and did exactly what I wanted. Marked as answer

Answer (score 2):

Since "attendees" is an Array, use filter to extract those addresses whose names startsWith "!" on each element and using map to map out the name field.

Input:

```
{
  "context": "context",
  "meetings": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "subject": "subject 123",
      "attendees": [
        {
          "type": "required",
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "!user1",
            "address": "user1@gmail.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "required",
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "!user2",
            "address": "user2@gmail.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": 456,
      "subject": "subject 456",
      "attendees": [
        {
          "type": "required",
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "user3",
            "address": "user3@gmail.com"
          }
        },
        {
          "type": "required",
          "emailAddress": {
            "name": "user4",
            "address": "user4@gmail.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

DW:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
payload.meetings map ((item, index) -> {
  id: item.id,
  subject: item.subject,
  attendees: item.attendees,
  (do {
    var data = item.attendees.emailAddress filter ($.name startsWith "!")
    ---
    // map email field to the address from output of data stored above , if none present no email field will be in output
    {
      (email: data.address) if (!isEmpty(data))
    }
  })
}) filter !isEmpty($.email)
// filters required Objects from final output
```

Output :

```
[
  {
    "id": 123,
    "subject": "subject 123",
    "attendees": [
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "!user1",
          "address": "user1@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "!user2",
          "address": "user2@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ],
    "email": [
      "user1@gmail.com",
      "user2@gmail.com"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": 456,
    "subject": "subject 456",
    "attendees": [
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "user3",
          "address": "user3@gmail.com"
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "required",
        "emailAddress": {
          "name": "user4",
          "address": "user4@gmail.com"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your suggestion. In your output, it contains the object (id: 456) where the name NOT starting with "!". But my requirement is that the output should contains only the objects that having the name that starts with "!". I think the overall filter is missing

Comment: If thats the case, I edited the DW.

Comment: Thank you @Stackoverflowed. Your answer satisifed my requirement except the "email" should be a string in my case. So, modified that according to the snippet shared by LeanCabeza and it gives the expected result now. Thanks much for your contribution